# Is it possible to generate Allure report in python-unittest?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest, allure

I have found solution for allure report in Pytest. But I need to generate allure report in python-unittest. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

By adding allure decorators

- @allure.story('Story/Requirement Name')
- @allure.feature('Feature Name')
- @allure.testcase("Test Case name")

for instance

```
def test_nameOfTheTest(self):
    with allure.step("Open browser"):
```

or at the definitions you can use

```
@allure.step("Open application") 
def open_application(self):
```

**for running the tests:**

```
python -m pytest nameOftheFile.py(considering its in the root) --alluredir ./results
```

Getting the results:

```
allure serve ./results/
```

Hope this should help you

Comment: As I understood correctly Rahat is wondering how to do it with unittest not pytest

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys, os, pytest, subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Run allure report of this file, export report to PJ/Reports
    pytest.main(['-s', '-q','--alluredir','path_store_allure_report,'Test.py'])
    #Open allue report via browser
    subprocess.run([r'powershell.exe', r'allure ' + 'serve ' + 'path_store_allure_report'])
```

I using this code to my Test_runner.py and it's can export and open report on browser after done code